# Volume Mixer Control and Listing Applications

Tags: c#, arduino, controls, volume

I have been working on a little project seeing if i can turn my arduino into a volume mixer using potentiometers. I have been creating a program in C# visual studio and i have managed to get the arduino sending data through the serial port to visual studio and studio being able to read my values. So what i am needing help with is changing system volume depending on the device name i provide. I also want to know if it possible to list all the application sessions running under a certain device so that the user can select a application and change the volume independently, without changing the main volume.

Thanks for your time,
Joe

Answer (score -1):

I am doing something similar and have it working for the most part using a class.  It does have times where it fails but other then that all you will need to do is pass in app name and volume percentage you want it to go to.  For more details like the exact issues here is the link: [C# per application volume control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439454/c-sharp-per-application-volume-control)